# Check if each corresponding digit in two numbers sum to the same total?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm brand new to C# and I've been absolutely stumped by a problem.

I'm trying to add each digit of a user input in a console app that are the same length (ex: Number 1 = 123 &  Number 2 = 456).  So I want to to check and see if 1+4=2+5=3+6 and then say if it's true or false.

My problem is, I don't know how to single out each individual digit that has been input. I feel like I'm absolutely overthinking this, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code? You do not wan't use to give you the whole thing but seems interested by a part of it, so show us what you have already done! [mcve], [ask].

Comment: User input is always a `string` and you can access individual characters of a string pretty easily

Comment: Let's take `456`; `456 % 10 == 6`; `456 / 10 % 10 == 5`, `456 / 10 / 10 % 10 = 4`... Can you see the pattern? Another possibility is `456.ToString()[i] - '0'` where `i = 0, 1, 2`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631909/int-to-char-array. It will answer your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-turn-an-int-into-an-array-of-ints-of-each-digit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's solve the problem in *general case* and in the *most accurate* way. First we should answer two questions:

1. What shall we do with *negative numbers*? Just *ignore* the minus `-` or return `false`?
2. What if numbers have *different lengths*, e.g. `52` and `3`? Shall we pad `3` to `03` (and thus return `true`) or return `false`?

Implementation

```
  public static bool Solution(int left, right) {
    // Comment this out (drop) if you accept negative numbers
    if (left < 0 || right < 0)
      return false;

    // Trim('-') - trimming '-' if we have negative numbers
    string A = left.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim('-');
    string B = right.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim('-');

    // Comment this out (drop) if you want to pad numbers with different lengths
    if (A.Length != B.Length)
      return false;

    // Padding with zeroes if required
    if (A.Length > B.Length)
      B = B.PadLeft(A.Length, '0');
    else if (B.Length > A.Length)
      A = A.PadLeft(B.Length, '0');

    // Finally, we can check
    for (int i = 1; i < A.Length; ++i)
      if (A[i] + B[i] != A[0] + B[0])
        return false; // Do we have a counter example?

    return true;   
  }
```

Comment: `A[n]+B[n] == A[n]B[n]` (concatenated). Need to parse the ints at that point

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: no, `A[n]` is of type `char`, that's why `A[n]+B[n]` will be of type `int` (and no concatenation). Technically, it should have been `A[i] - '0' + B[i] - '0' == A[0] - '0' + B[0] - '0'`, but we can simplify and get rid of `'0'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ:

```
string number1 = "123";
string number2 = "456";

bool equalSums = number1
    .Zip(number2, (c1, c2) => Convert.ToInt32(c1) + Convert.ToInt32(c2))
    .Distinct()
    .Count() == 1;
```

`Enumerable.Zip` links two sequences via index, so char1 of first string is linked with char1 of other string and so on. `Convert.ToInt32` converts the character to `int` and builds the sum of the two digits. Then `Distinct` removes duplicates and `Count` checks if there is only one number remaining which means all where equal.

Comment: Fails if input have different lengths, e.g. 123 and 10.

Comment: @Greg: OP has stated that they are always same length, it was one of the requirements: _"....user input in a console app that are the same length"_. But of course you have to precheck, f.e. with `int.TryParse` and `String.Length`

Comment: You are right, missed that. What is also cool with your solution, you can compare words as well. abc | cba = True

Answer (score -1):

This is a great problem to show the power of regex, assuming your numbers are stored in properties,

```
string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
string num2 = Console.ReadLine();

 int[] numbers1 = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(num1 , @"\d") select 
 int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();

 int[] numbers2 = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(num2 , @"\d") select int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
```

Then you have two number arrays you can tests out e/g

```
if (numbers1[1] + numbers2[1] == numbers1[2] + numbers2[2])
{
Console.WriteLine("aye its true");
}
else {
//do something else
}
```

I hope that answers your question

P.S. I used [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) for testing my regex, its a nice tool

Comment: Using a regex here only complicates the problem. Also instead of `@"\d+"` at least use `@"\d"` (or even `"."`). Give me some time @JohnChris.

Comment: Fair enough. Problem is though, with `"@\d+"` you regex matches the entire string and your array would only contain one member: The original number.

Comment: I didn't downvote but from my reading it's hard to understand your point: your convertion of a int to string, then a select , then a to array.. 
I'm not sure what happends here.

Comment: Then the second part is even more weird. `numbers1[1] + numbers2[1] == numbers1[2] + numbers2[2]` .. is clearly weird. how do you build that? The starting index is 0 not 1 thats disturbing.

Comment: I was assuming he kept the values in properties like my answer, said - i removed that fine, I gave an example of how he can test, ignoring the starting array integer, i didnt want to give a full solution, let him think a bit...

Comment: You gave help only on Casting user input into int array. It's a step in the good direction still regex is not what comes first here. I 'm trying to find what would cause a downvote. There is no judging.

Comment: Fair enough... and i made a mistake initially with my casting to an array, so all good.

Comment: cleanning up my comment, as they are a bit chatty.